# How to replace vaccine yellow book in UK?

Tags: uk, vaccinations

I'm an American citizen living in London. I have a yellow vaccine booklet that is originally from the US and is about 13 years old now, filled with all my requisite vaccinations, most importantly yellow fever.

However, the vaccine booklet has come separated and each page stands individually. This happened on my last trip to a country checking yellow fever vaccines, just before COVID, and I was warned by the immigration officer that I had better get it fixed as it is technically invalid in that state.

Is there a way to replace the vaccine booklet in the UK, despite it originating in America, without having to get re-vaccinated?

Answer (score 5):

If it works in the UK like it does in the Netherlands, any doctor or clinic who can do vaccinations can give you a new one.

Of course they may not have the right stamps for the specific vaccines you had in the past, which might cause problems, but worth a try.

And of course do keep in mind that most vaccines are only valid for a limited period, so you might need some of them redone anyway.

Comment: In Germany these booklets can be bought in most pharmacies (Apotheke). See **How do you get the vaccination certificates?** at: [Your guide to travel vaccination certificates - practio.co.uk](https://practio.co.uk/travel-health/articles/vaccination-certificate)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check this option out. If it works, I will mark as correct.

Comment: The UK (or at least England) seems fairly unusual in that it does not seem to produce such cards or documentations. I've resided my whole life in England receiving a whole variety of vaccinations and have never possessed or seen any card or document with them listed on. I believe vaccinations are meant to be tracked in medical records, but I'm not sure how reliably they actually are.

Comment: @CMaster I believe they're generally fairly good at tracking them within a surgery, but if the patient gets some vaccinations not through the GP where they're registered, or they register with a new surgery it's not unusual for records to end up incomplete. When I first changed my registration for university the new place had no records of any of my vaccinations, but the place I'm currently registered with seems to have all my records from the entire period. I'm not sure if that's due to better records sharing, or the last place messing up though

Comment: @CMaster they are (or at least were) certainly issued by private travel clinics, specifically for vaccinations required to enter another country, in the prescribed international format. As mentioned by the OP yellow fever is the big one. Vaccinations required domestically are treated rather differently. https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/yellow-fever/vaccination/

Comment: You're correct that many vaccines work for a limited period of time, but for the specific case of a Yellow Fever vaccine for international travel, the immunity is now considered to be lifelong, and a yellow book stating that revaccination is needed after 10 years is out-of-date and can be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I've received a book (although not a "yellow" one or very standardized, but then it wasn't yellow fever) for private travel jabs before.

My point was mostly to doubt that a standard doctor would necessarily be able to duplicate the damaged document.

Comment: Children in the UK are given red books to record vaccinations and various other health items. I'm not sure if they are still any use/relevant once they grow up though.